# bootstrap class media in one row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I use class media bootstrap to listing the contact information. It gives me this result :

[image]

I want the detail contacts to be in one row (not stacking like that). I did the div class=row but doesn't give me what I want.

this is my code :

```html
<section id="kontak">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2>Kontak</h2>
                <hr class="hr-line">
                <h5>Konfirmasi Pembayaran atau Informasi Lainnya Silahkan Hubungi Kami Di</h5>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">

        <div class="media">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="media-left"><img class="media-object" src="<?php echo base_url('asset/img/whatsapp.jpg');?>" alt="..."></div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">Whatsapp</h4>
                    <h5>+62-898-2057-545</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="media">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="media-left"><img class="media-object" src="<?php echo base_url('asset/img/email.jpg') ?>" alt="..."></div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">Email</h4>
                    <h7><strong>kirimundangandotcom@gmail.com</strong></h7>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="media">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="media-left"><img class="media-object" src="<?php echo base_url('asset/img/phone.png') ?>" alt="..."></div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">Telepon</h4>
                    <h5>+62-898-2057-545</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your media blocks are inside out...

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left"><img class="media-object" src="<?php echo base_url('asset/img/email.jpg') ?>" alt="..."></div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="media-heading">Email</h4>
                <h7><strong>kirimundangandotcom@gmail.com</strong></h7>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

your `.col_*` blocks should be the only direct children of your `.row`s. everything in a row should be in a column.

Comment: @Maii - happy to help. if this answered your question please hit the checkmark by the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

only thing you need is to remove div with class media

```html
<section id="kontak">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2>Kontak</h2>
                <hr class="hr-line">
                <h5>Konfirmasi Pembayaran atau Informasi Lainnya Silahkan Hubungi Kami Di</h5>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="media-left"><img class="media-object" src="<?php echo base_url('asset/img/whatsapp.jpg');?>" alt="..."></div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">Whatsapp</h4>
                    <h5>+62-898-2057-545</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="media-left"><img class="media-object" src="<?php echo base_url('asset/img/email.jpg') ?>" alt="..."></div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">Email</h4>
                    <h7><strong>kirimundangandotcom@gmail.com</strong></h7>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="media-left"><img class="media-object" src="<?php echo base_url('asset/img/phone.png') ?>" alt="..."></div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">Telepon</h4>
                    <h5>+62-898-2057-545</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        

        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is not correct

`<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="media">
      - - - - -  - - 
    </div>
  </div>`

. I take your example. check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z22oxbap/1/)